# Help with proving that the operation $a*b=a+b-2$ has no identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

We define an operation $a * b = a+b-2$ over $\mathbb R^2$ for every $a,b\in \mathbb R$.

Prove that there is no identity element for the operation.

Comment: What leads you to believe that there is no identity element?

Comment: Suppose $a + x -2 = x + a - 2 = a$ then $x =2$ ... and that's it.  That's the identity.  But I *strongly* suspect that isn't the actual question. In particular "on top of R^2" sounds like you have on operation on ordered pairs (a,b) $\in \mathbb R^2$.  But ... then that isn't a binary operation and it doesn't map to $R^2$.  What *exactly* is the question as stated?

Comment: In that context the question doesn't make any sense.  "$f:X \rightarrow Y$.  $X = \mathbb R^2$ and $Y = \mathbb R$.  $f(a,b) = a+b -2$.  Prove $f$ has no identity element."  What does *mean*?  It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: the operation is defined for R2, but a and b are members of R, as Omnomnomnom descirbed it.

Comment: In case the op is in R, then the approach is clear and simple, while with the team help, we managed to describe the question properly, how to we approach it ?

Comment: It is the *relation* that is in $\mathbb R^2$, where $(a, b)$ is an element of the relation (which you have named $*$),  if and only if $a*b= a+b-2$, for $a \in \mathbb R, b \in \mathbb R$

Comment: I reiterate Sloan's question: What gave you the idea that there was no identity element?  Is there an "answer in the back of the book" that suggests this, or is it part of the problem statement?  Without further elaboration, $2$ is clearly an identity element.

Comment: In my opinion @amWhy got it right, the thing here is not the issue of identity, but to identify the domain->range issue of the question, otherwise there is no point in asking it.  So to reiterate my understanding, basically the operation simple takes any tuple of 2 elements (a,b) from R2 and relate it through * to a member of R. It basically dictate that there is no closure over the operation in R2, so for sure there is no identity, and that's the point here, to realize this trick

Comment: @amWhy, I'd love to have your feedback

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. So for $(a, b) \in \mathbb R^2$, define $a*b= a+b-2 \in \mathbb R$.  Essentially, $*$ is a function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x, y) = x + y -2$

Comment: I appreciate your assistance and support in sharpening the way this question was asked and clarity in understanding it. Thank You

Comment: "it doesn't take a genius to figure that the OP has attempted to express "over the given set" using "on top of the given set.""  It wasn't "the on top of" that confused me; it was the "$R^2$".  The statement is clearly about a binary operation on R, not R^2, and as the binary operation *does* have an identity I seriously do not know what the text meant. "every once in a while some user just likes to harass new users, or nit-pick. My comment above yours was directed at such a user!"  That is a very nasty accusation and not at all true.

Comment: What I do notice is that for each of $(a, b)$ in $\{(6,6), (4, 8), (8, 4), (2, 10), (10, 2), (3, 9), (9, 3), (7, 5), (5, 7), (1, 11), (11, 1), (0, 12), (12, 0)\}$, $a*b$ = 10.

Comment: I've deleted my comment. I was not actually referring to you, @fleablood, when I referred to harassing posters. I'm sorry if it struck you othewise.

Comment: But there *is* closure, and there *is* an identity.  f(a,2) = a.  and f(a,b) = a+b-2 in R for all (a,b) in R^2.  So it might be clear to you, but I'm still utterly perplexed.

Comment: I'm getting there, @fleablood. Admittedly, we have all spent a good amount of time to clarify what this about, and where the problem is.  I also see closure.  But there is no unique identity: e.g. $f(2, a) = a$. By definition, I believe, the identity is to be unique.  But there is no way to take $f(a, b)$ and get (a, b) back.  And there's also a problem with inverses, see the set I list above,

Comment: I'm not getting it.  $a+e-2=e+a-2=a \iff a=2$ so there is an identity.  $a + b-2 = b+a - 2 = 2 \iff b = 4 - a$ so inverses exist.  $a*(b*c) = a*(b+c -2) = a+b+c -4 = (a+b -2) + c - 2=(a*b)*c$ so it's associative. And $a*b \in R$ and defined for all a,b in R so it's proper binary operation.  For any $x$ in R there are $a, b= a' * x=4-a+x-2=2-a+x$ so that $a*b= a + 2-a+x -2 =x$.  So everything we want to make this a group is there.  The only thing I can think of is that the proof wasn't to prove there was "not" but to prove there "was". ?????

Comment: @fleablood  I don't get why you have NOT yet read the OPs comments and confirmation.  The OP has made it clear that $*$, a function, takes $(a, b) \in \mathbb R^2$ to the set of Reals by defining $f(a, b) = a*b = a + b-2$. You came to this question and decided your interpretation is correct, failing to keep an open mind, failing to rethink your interpretation.  You answered when you answered, and that's fine.  But to insist, a half hour later, when matters have been pretty well clarified, and just reiterated your position. I'm done here.

Comment: @Hector Just ping me later if all the answers are more confusing than helpful, and we can discuss more in a chatroom, or I'll post an answer myself.

Comment: $a*e =a \forall a \iff a+e -2 = a \forall a \iff e= 2 \forall a \iff e + a -2 = a \forall a \iff e*a=a \forall a$.  So 2 is a unique and universal left and right identity.  $a*x = 2 \iff a+x - 2=2 \iff x = 4-a \iff x+a -2 =2 \iff x*a =2$ so a unique inverse exists for all $a$.  What more do we want? It's closed ($a*b \in R\forall a,b \in R$) It's complete ($\forall x\in R; \exists a,b\in R| a*b = x;$ take $b=2-a +x=a'*x$).  It's even associative.  It's ...  binary operation that makes $R$ a group.

Comment: I said it 10 min. ago and I'll say it again, @fleablood. AFAIK, this conversation is over.

Comment: I think that this is one of the MANY cases where the OP was correct from the very beginning and the text was wrong.  2 *is* the identity element of the operation.  Plain and simple.  If we interpret this, as we can, as f:R^2 -> R, that's all very fine but then *what is the question*?

Comment: I copied the full and correct question as stated in the assignment.   some were saying that there is a closure, I disagree as the op is from R2 to R, how can be a closure if the domain and the range are not the same ?    It is clear that from this nature there will be no identity element. it is clear as well that a * b = b * a.  however I wonder if for proving associative the classical approach of  (a * b) * c = a * (b * c) will not work, as it is meaning less to have the op with c as it works on pairs. should associative prove be made over (a * b) * (c * d) = a * (b * c) * d?

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $a*b = a+ b - 2$ then for all $a \in \mathbb R$ if $a*x = x*a =a$ then $a+x -2 = x +a -2 =a$ and $x =2$.  That's true for all $a \in \mathbb R$ and it is the only value where it is true so $2$ is the identity element.

*BUT* if $a,b \in \mathbb R^2$ and $a*b = a+ b - 2= (a_1,a_2) + (b_1,b_2) + (2,0) = (a_1+b_1 + 2,a_2 + b_2)$ and $a + x - 2=a $ then $(a_1 + x_1 + 2, a_2+z_2) = (a_1,a_2)$ so $(x_1, x_2) = (2,0)$ and ... I got nothing.

But if this is a *unary* operation.... $(a,b) \in \mathbb R^2$ and $f(a,b) = a+b -2 \in \mathbb R$ .... but then it's a) unary not binary so identities don't make sense as we don't every operate on two elements for one to "invert" the other and b) it's not an "operation" as it doesn't map to the original set $\mathbb R^2$.  So the question makes no sense in that terms.

So, I got nothing.  I think the question must mean something else.  I'm particularly concerned about that near non-sense phrase "on top of $\mathbb R^2$".  I don't know what that is supposed to mean in this context.

====

Okay, the only real way I see this question as making sense is not as an algebra question at all and not about the identity or inverse elements of a group but as a prove that as a function from $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow R$ there is no *inverse* **function** $f^{-1}:\mathbb R \rightarrow R^2$ so that $f^{-1}(f(a,b)) = (a,b)$.

For any $x \in R$ there are multiple $(a,b)$ so that $f(a,b) =x$ so there can't be any $f^{-1}$ that magically "knows" that $f^{-1}(x)$ is supposed to equal $(a,b)$ as opposed to $(a+e, b-e)$.  i.e.  For any $x \in R$ there are infinitely many $(x + d, 2 - d)$ so that $f((x+d, 2-d)) = x+d + 2-d -2 = x$.

Thus for any $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow R^2$ so that $f(a,b) = x$ and $g(x) = (a,b)$ we would also have $f(a+d, b-d)= a+d +b-d -2 = a+b-2 = f(a,b) = x$ but $g(f(a+d,b-d)) = (a,b) \ne (a+d,b-d)$ so there can be no inverse function.

But that's not an algebra question.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies.

Comment: While this question is wrongly translated to English, it stated that the operation a*b = a+b-2 for a,b in R but * is in R2. This is the part that confuse me as well.

Comment: If $a,b\in\mathbb R^2$, then $a+b-2$ doesn't make any sense, because $2\not\in \mathbb R^2$

Comment: The usual way of notating binary relations over $U$ to $V$ is $*:U \times U \to V$, which can just as sensibly be written as $*:U^2 \to V$.  One can say that $*$ is an operator over $U^2$, or that it is a binary operator over $U$.

Comment: So.... we want to find $e \in R$ so that $(a,e)\rightarrow a+e - 2 = a$?  That'd be 2.  Not sure I see the point.  The question is still wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for reading the comments, and answering as best as anyone could have. The latter (and former) pretty much captures what I concluded. Thanks for posting both the takes on the question. +1

Answer (score 1):

Very probably you intended the question to be about a binary operation $*$ on $\mathbb R$, and "over $\mathbb R^2$" just refers to the fact that such an operation is a function with domain  $\mathbb R^2$.  Assuming that's indeed your intention, the formula $a*b=a+b-2$ makes sense; it defines a binary operation $*$ on $\mathbb R$.  But you won't be able to prove that it has no identity, because in fact $2$ is an identity for this operation. Just compute: $a*2=a+2-2=a$ and $2*b=2+b-2=b$.

Comment: See the comment thread below the op....it seems that $*: \mathbb R^2 \to R$ such that for every $(a, b) \in \mathbb R^2$, $a*b= a + b -2 \in \mathbb R.$ I find it easier to simply note that we have $f: \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(a, b) = a+b -2.$

Comment: But then what is the question?  f(a,b) = a+b-2.  What are we supposed to *answer* about it?  Are we just supposed to note "Yes, that's a function, all right"?

Comment: @fleablood I took the question to be "I have to prove that there is no identity element for this operation" (the OP's second sentence).  See also the title of the question.

Comment: But... there *IS* an identity element for the operation!  You can *not* prove there is not one when there is!

Comment: See... the problem is the OP got confused because he prove 2 *was* the identity.  I asked what an operation "over R^2" was supposed to mean and suggested maybe the question was misinterpreted.  Somewhere along the way if was noted that $* = $ binary operation on R.  Is the same as $a*b = f(a,b); f:R\times R \rightarrow R$. amWhy and the poor confused OP seemed to think that utterly changed the question to something else entirely. But it doesn't.  f transfers the question to the far less direct but equivalent: "Prove there is no e so that f(a,b)=a for all a".  That there *IS* is still an issue.

Comment: @fleablood Your next-to-last comment seems to just repeat what I said in the last two sentences of my answer.  It seems to me that, when someone asks how to prove X, and X happens to be false, the reasonable answer is to say that X can't be proved because it's false.

Comment: In other words my comment wasn't for you but amWhy who seems to think $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow R;f(a,b) = a+b - 2$ is the answer.  To which, I have to ask, the answer to *what*?  What question is $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow R;f(a,b) = a+b - 2$ the answer to?

Comment: Sorry.  I saw you answer nearly a day after I posted and figured it was in response to my question to amWhy and to what his (rather rude IMO) criticism of your answer that everything changes with $f(a,b) = a*b$.  My question was, if this changes the question then what does it change it to?  In my sleepiness I assumed you were trying to answer that.

Comment: Bottom line: you and the op originally are right.  amWhy muddied the waters hopelessly and convinced that op that he was originally  confused and that the question had some obtuse meaning that it doesn't.  Now the newly confused op and amWhy are babbling incoherently.  It was a simple question... and it was wrong.  binary operation means $a*b=f(a,b);f:S\times S \rightarrow S$.  Identity element means $e$ such that $f(a,e)=f(e,a)=a;\forall a \in S$.ie. $a*e=e*a=a;\forall a$  In this case  $e$ = 2.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to be very certain of what we are dealing with:

Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x-2$.  Then $f$ is a bijection, and $f(a\ast b) = f(a) + f(b)$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

This shows that the structure $(\mathbb{R},\ast)$ is equivalent to the structure $(\mathbb{R},+)$, and inherits all its properties.  Since $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is an abelian group with identity $0$, $(\mathbb{R},\ast)$ is an abelian group with identity $f^{-1}(0) = 2$.

Comment: Have y0u even followed the comment thread below the post; we are way past that, and you've misinterpreted what the OP clarified in a comment made almost thirty minutes ago, verified by OP 20 minutes ago.  Your post doesn't bear on the question intended.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, I read the comments and I understand your interpretation of the question.  If you believe that you are right, your energy is probably best spent coming up with a clarifying edit to the question.  However, in my view I am using the standard definition of an identity of a binary operation, which is usually defined to be a function $S^2\to S$ for some set $S$.

Comment: @amWhy More specifically, the post did not specify whether the operation was arity 2 or arity 1.  You say 1, I say 2.  I don't really see a way of resolving this without the input of the person who wrote the question.